# How do I make TypeScript treat my file as a module?

Tags: typescript, es6-modules

From https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html:

> In TypeScript, just as in ECMAScript 2015, any file containing a top-level `import` or `export` is considered a module. Conversely, a file without any top-level `import` or `export` declarations is treated as a script whose contents are available in the global scope (and therefore to modules as well).

This behavior is surprising and unwanted, how do I prevent it?

Consider a TypeScript module written for its side effects, `lib.ts`,

```js
var myglobal = 3;
console.log(`lib.ts: myglobal = ${myglobal}`);
```

Then consider `main.ts`, a file which imports `lib.ts` for its side effects:

```js
import './lib.js';
console.log(`main.ts: myglobal = ${myglobal}`);
```

For completeness, I provide a `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["ES2015", "DOM"],
    "module": "ES2015",
    "strict": true
  },
  "files": ["main.ts", "lib.ts"]
}
```

It seems like this **should** fail to compile, but tsc succeeds, much to my dismay. I then bundle the result with rollup.js,

```js
export default {
  input: "main.js",
  output: {
    file: "bundle.js",
    format: "module",
  },
};
```

The resulting output shows that Rollup and TypeScript clearly disagree about whether `myglobal` in `lib.ts` is visible from `main.ts`, since Rollup notices that `myglobal` is a free variable in `main` and concludes that it should be renamed in `lib`.

```js
var myglobal$1 = 3;
console.log("lib.ts: myglobal = " + myglobal$1);

console.log("main.ts: myglobal = " + myglobal);
```

When I run it, it fails.

```
$ node bundle.js 
lib.ts: myglobal = 3
/redacted/bundle.js:4
console.log("main.ts: myglobal = " + myglobal);
                                     ^

ReferenceError: myglobal is not defined
    at Object. (/redacted/bundle.js:4:38)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

What should have been a compile-time error in TypeScript is now a run-time error. How do I configure TypeScript to treat `lib.js` as a module, as I intend?

(Searching the ES2015 spec, I cannot find any support for the claim that "any file containing a top-level `import` or `export` is considered a module". In fact, it seems like whether or not a file is a module is determined before parsing even begins, since it affects what the goal symbol is for a JavaScript parser. So, does this part of the TypeScript documentation make any sense?)

Answer (score 3):

Whether a file is a module or not depends on the context by which it is loaded, which TS has no way of knowing, so needs some clue based on the file content. Since files that don't import or export *anything* are very rare, `import` and `export` declarations are used to infer whether a file is a module or not.

You can add `export { }` to a file to make it into a module.

Comment: Maybe it's rare to do this on purpose, I was hoping to also catch cases where this happens by accident. It's easy enough to forget to put "export" on a variable, and I was hoping to use TypeScript to catch this (relatively common) class of errors.

Comment: YMMV but in my experience, if you're writing actual code, it's extremely difficult to get more than 20 lines into a file without writing an `import`. Just logistically, you can't really have more than a handful of files in any project with zero imports, so worrying about this category of error happening again is not time well-spent.

Comment: Perhaps my project is an outlier, then. This project has a lot of leaf modules. This surprising behavior from the TypeScript compiler took a lot of effort to track down and reduce to this simple test case, and some of the error messages were unhelpful or misleading (e.g. when combined with jsx=react-jsxdev), so forgive me if I disagree about whether it's "time well-spent".

Answer (score 2):

Attempting to compile with '--isolatedModules' will instantly error on any file Typescript does not perceive as a module. It has also limits the use of some typescript features.